# Inequality involving $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Can anybody explain me, why the following inequality is true?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{k \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}}^{(k+1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}} \left| \frac{\sin \xi}{\xi} \right| \, \text{d} \xi \geq  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left| \sin\left( (k+1) \pi - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\right|}{(k+1) \pi - \frac{\pi}{4}} \  \frac{\pi}{2} $$

The question is motivated from the following calculation
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1) \pi} \left| \frac{\sin \xi}{\xi} \right| \, \text{d} \xi \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{k \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}}^{(k+1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}} \left| \frac{\sin \xi}{\xi} \right| \, \text{d} \xi \geq \\
\geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left| \sin\left( (k+1) \pi - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\right|}{(k+1) \pi - \frac{\pi}{4}} \  \frac{\pi}{2} =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left| \sin\left( (k+1) \pi - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\right|}{2(k+1)  - \frac{1}{2}} = \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \frac{1}{2(k+1)  - \frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4k+3} \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4k} = \\
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} = \infty
$$
which shows that $\frac{\sin \xi}{\xi} \notin \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the fact that $$\int_a^b |f(x)|\ge  (b-a)\inf_{x\in(a,b)} |f(x)|$$and that $\left|\frac{\sin x}x\right|$ is minimised on $(k\pi +\frac\pi4, (k+1)\pi -\frac\pi4)$ when $x=(k+1)\pi -\frac\pi4$

Comment: You should have the inverse inequality, with inf. That function is not increasing.

Comment: The right inequality is not true in general (it's possible that $\int f=0$ and $f \neq 0$); you need only to compare left and right terms.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

For $x\in[k\pi+\pi/4,(k+1)\pi-\pi/4]$,

$$|\sin x|\ge|\sin\big((k+1)\pi-\pi/4\big)|$$

and

$$x\le(k+1)\pi-\pi/4$$